# Problems with SUMIFS function

Tags: google-sheets

I don't understand why SUMIFS function works with some columns in the same worksheets and for others it doesn't. This is my formula:

```
=SUMIFS(EURO;AGENZIE;"ABN";MESI1;"01")
```

where `EURO`, `AGENZIE`, `ABN` AND `MESI1` are the name of some columns in the same sheet. The formula is needed to add the values in the `EURO` column when the condition in others columns is that they are equal to `ABN` (`AGENZIE`) and month is January (`MESI1=01`). Column `AGENZIE` had other values, and when they are used instead of `ABN` the formula seems to work.

My question is: how is it possible that the same formula works depending on the value I use as condition?
I don't get any error, only the result is zero when it should be <>0.
Thanks for helping me solve this problem

Comment: Welcome. Please share the link to a test sheet so as to see the issue and try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the range properly, not call it "Euro" or "Agenzie" but "A:A", and "B:B" say. Then it all works fine. Have a look at the definition of SUMIFS in the documentation.

This is the formula that should do:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"ABN",C:C,"01")
```

Below is a screenshot of what I understand you're trying to achieve:
[image]